# Cannot add new Azure Active Directory user to a database immediately

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a PowerShell script that looks as follows. Basically what this is doing is adding a new user to our Azure Active Directory and then attempting to add the user to a database.

```
# Create some variables
$TemporaryPassword = "Password123"
$DisplayName = "xxxxxxxxx"
$MailNickName = "xxxxxxxx"
$PrincipalName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create a password profile which the New-AzureADUser cmdlet needs
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = $TemporaryPassword

#Add the user to AAD
New-AzureADUser -AccountEnabled $True -DisplayName $DisplayName -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -MailNickName $MailNickName -UserPrincipalName $PrincipalName

# If the user was added successfully, add him/her to our database.
$Status = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$PrincipalName'"
if ($Status)
{
    Invoke-Expression "&'C:\AzureFileShare\MEDsys\Powershell Scripts\AddDatabaseUser.ps1' -ServerName medsys-dev -DatabaseName Phoenix -UserName $PrincipalName"
}
```

This script is executing successfully except that I'm not able to add the user to the database (which is what the AddDatabaseUser.ps1 script does) immediately. I will always get an error saying the user doesn't exist in AAD. However, if I wait another 5-15 seconds and just execute that particular line again, it works.

So it seems that even though the user is added to AAD successfully, some sort of delay is necessary before Azure allows the user to be added to a database. Does anyone know why?

Note: I didn't add the AddDatabaseUser.ps1 script to this as I don't think the issue is there because the user is always added if I want long enough after he/she is added to AAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is simply the challenges of replicating data across a large global cloud identity system. When you create your new user, it takes a little time for that change to propagate across all copies of the directory that we have in our different clusters and regions. When you make the `Get-AzureADUser`, you might not be hitting the same clusters or regions which have picked up the changes yet, hence the 10 second delay for the results to work.

The solution here is to use the output of the `New-AzureADUser` call to populate your database, and avoid the `Get-AzureAdUser`.

If you make a call like this:

```
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> $result = New-AzureADUser -AccountEnabled $true -UserPrincipalName "new@shawntest.onmicrosoft.com"-DisplayName "new name" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -MailNickName "newname"
```

and then check the value of `$result`:

```
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> $result |fl


ExtensionProperty              : {[odata.metadata, https://graph.windows.net/4a4d599f-e69d-4cd8-a9e1-9882ea340fb5/$meta
                                 data#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element], [odata.type,
                                 Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User], [employeeId, ], [onPremisesDistinguishedName, ]...}
DeletionTimestamp              :
ObjectId                       : 49ebc6d5-835b-447c-bed0-3281f63cf7c2
ObjectType                     : User
AccountEnabled                 : True
AssignedLicenses               : {}
AssignedPlans                  : {}
City                           :
CompanyName                    :
Country                        :
CreationType                   :
Department                     :
DirSyncEnabled                 :
DisplayName                    : new name
FacsimileTelephoneNumber       :
GivenName                      :
IsCompromised                  :
ImmutableId                    :
JobTitle                       :
LastDirSyncTime                :
Mail                           :
MailNickName                   : newname
Mobile                         :
OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier   :
OtherMails                     : {}
PasswordPolicies               :
PasswordProfile                : class PasswordProfile {
                                   Password:
                                   ForceChangePasswordNextLogin: True
                                   EnforceChangePasswordPolicy: False
                                 }

PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName     :
PostalCode                     :
PreferredLanguage              :
ProvisionedPlans               : {}
ProvisioningErrors             : {}
ProxyAddresses                 : {}
RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime : 11/2/2017 8:39:28 PM
ShowInAddressList              :
SignInNames                    : {}
SipProxyAddress                :
State                          :
StreetAddress                  :
Surname                        :
TelephoneNumber                :
UsageLocation                  :
UserPrincipalName              : new@shawntest.onmicrosoft.com
UserType                       : Member
```

This will be exactly the same results as `Get-AzureAdUser`:

```
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId 49ebc6d5-835b-447c-bed0-3281f63cf7c2 | fl


ExtensionProperty              : {[odata.metadata, https://graph.windows.net/4a4d599f-e69d-4cd8-a9e1-9882ea340fb5/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User/@Element], [odata.type, Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User], [employeeId, ],
                                 [onPremisesDistinguishedName, ]...}
DeletionTimestamp              :
ObjectId                       : 49ebc6d5-835b-447c-bed0-3281f63cf7c2
ObjectType                     : User
AccountEnabled                 : True
AssignedLicenses               : {}
AssignedPlans                  : {}
City                           :
CompanyName                    :
Country                        :
CreationType                   :
Department                     :
DirSyncEnabled                 :
DisplayName                    : new name
FacsimileTelephoneNumber       :
GivenName                      :
IsCompromised                  :
ImmutableId                    :
JobTitle                       :
LastDirSyncTime                :
Mail                           :
MailNickName                   : newname
Mobile                         :
OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier   :
OtherMails                     : {}
PasswordPolicies               :
PasswordProfile                : class PasswordProfile {
                                   Password:
                                   ForceChangePasswordNextLogin: True
                                   EnforceChangePasswordPolicy: False
                                 }

PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName     :
PostalCode                     :
PreferredLanguage              :
ProvisionedPlans               : {}
ProvisioningErrors             : {}
ProxyAddresses                 : {}
RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime : 11/2/2017 8:39:28 PM
ShowInAddressList              :
SignInNames                    : {}
SipProxyAddress                :
State                          :
StreetAddress                  :
Surname                        :
TelephoneNumber                :
UsageLocation                  :
UserPrincipalName              : new@shawntest.onmicrosoft.com
UserType                       : Member
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I now understand the problem. But I don't understand your solution. You said I should look at the results of the New-AzureAdUser call. What exactly am I looking for that tells me the new user has now been populated to all clusters and regions?

Comment: You should simply check the call was a success, and if there is any particular details you need, you can use the user object that was returned. My solution is simply saying you do not need to call the get user API, as the data it tells you is certainly redundant

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean now. But neither approach seems valid now because even though New-AzureADUser returns information about the user created, this doesn't mean I'm able to add the user to a database because of the time it takes to replicate the data across the planet. Correct?

Comment: Why must you adding a user to a database be dependent on replication in AAD?

Comment: Because it's a contained user being authenticated via AAD and I create the user as follows: CREATE USER [UserName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;